# python toolbox - def execute error

Tags: arcpy, python-toolbox

I am trying to make python toolbox. I used a converter to convert regular toolbox to python toolbox. It did the job, but I had to fix the code manually in some parts. When I did that, syntax was fine, but drop-down menu for selecting fields was missing. I managed to fix it, and get the menu. Code in which I get an error is working fine in regular toolbox, but not here. Here is the full code:

**EDIT** Whatever I do, I always get some kind of error in the "def execute" part of the code. I defined variables, and fixed the previous error. Error is for sure there in def execute part. This is the new code:

```
import arcpy

class Toolbox(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.label = "Alat"
        self.alias = "Alat_replace"
        self.tools = [Alatko]

class Alatko(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.label = "Label alata"
        self.description = "Insert znaka"
        self.canRunInBackground = True

    def getParameterInfo(self):
        # First parameter
        in_features = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Input Features",
            name="in_features",
            datatype="Feature Layer",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input")
        in_features.filter.list = ["Point"]

        # Second parameter
        field = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Field Name",
            name="field_name",
            datatype="Field",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input")

        field.parameterDependencies = [in_features.name]
        field.filter.list = ["Short","Long","Double","Float","Text"]

        # Third parameter
        sql = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="SQL_expres",
            name="SQL_Expression",
            datatype="SQL Expression",
            parameterType="Optional",
            direction="Input")

        sql.parameterDependencies = [in_features.name]

        # Fourth parameter
        Character = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Charcters",
            name="Char_string",
            datatype="String",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input")

        # Fifth parameter
        Position = arcpy.Parameter(
           displayName="PositionNR",
           name="Position",
           datatype="String",
           parameterType="Required",
           direction="Input")

        # Sixth parameter
        out_features = arcpy.Parameter(
           displayName="Output Features",
           name="out_features",
           datatype="Feature Layer",
           parameterType="Derived",
           direction="output")

        out_features.parameterDependencies = [in_features.name]

        params = [in_features, field, sql, Character, Position, out_features]
        return params

    def isLicensed(self):
        return True

    def updateMessages(self, parameters):
        in_features = parameters[0]
        field = parameters[1]
        sql = parameters[2]
        Character = parameters[3]
        Position = parameters[4]
        out_features = parameters[5]

    def execute(self, parameters, messages):
        in_features = parameters[0].valueAsText
        field = parameters[1].valueAsText
        sql = parameters[2].valueAsText
        Character = parameters[3].valueAsText
        Position = parameters[4].valueAsText
        out_features = parameters[5].valueAsText
        Position = int(Position)
        if Character == "#":
           cur = arcpy.UpdateCursor(table)
        else:
           cur = arcpy.UpdateCursor(table, Character)
        row = cur.next()
        while row:
            value = row.getValue(field)
            newValue = value[:Position] + Character + value[Position:]
            row.setValue(field, newValue)
            cur.updateRow(row)
            row = cur.next()
        del cur, row
```

The code imports specific characters into the field in desired position.

This is the window for input: 
feature class for input class
Field name for field name I want to insert character
sql for optional selection
Character is for character I want to put in
and positionNR is te number of position i want to put my character in

this is the example[image]

and this is the error

New error is:

**Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 100, in execute
NameError: global name 'table' is not defined**

Comment: If you can develop a code snippet (in this case a test.pyt) that targets figuring out how "to get drop-down list to select fields from the table" (and perhaps just printing its name) then once you solve that you should be able to plug it back into your actual tool.

Comment: What's the exact new (or current) error you are now getting after the updates?

Comment: I added the error I get when I try to execute this code. "Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 95, in execute ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'f'"

Comment: Can you also add what parameters you are providing when you run it (with sensitive/personal info removed is fine)? This looks like the value of 'f' was given for your 'PositionNR' parameter.

Comment: @EvilGenius, you are right, look at `Position = parameters[3].valueAsText` it's pulling from the Character field.  Dean when you added the sql parameter you didn't update the indexing in the execute part only in the updateMessages part.

Comment: I changed that now, thanks. I overlooked that part of the code. but i still have error: "Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 100, in execute
NameError: global name 'table' is not defined"- I updated the answer.

Comment: Shouldn't `table` be your first parameter, `in_features`?  That is the feature class you are trying to update?

Comment: Yes it should, and yes it is. I changed table to "in_features", but i get one big error

Comment: "<string>", line 84, in execute  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgisdesktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\__init__.py", line 1211, in UpdateCursor
 return gp.updateCursor(dataset, where_clause, spatial_reference, fields, sort_fields)   File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 364, in updateCursor self._gp.UpdateCursor(*gp_fixargs(args, True))) RuntimeError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.An invalid SQL statement was used.
An invalid SQL statement was used. [Export_Output] An invalid SQL statement was used. [SELECT * FROM Export_Output WHERE ( w )]"

Comment: It's failing on your where clause (Character variable).  You need to build a where clause with that character and pass that as the second argument.  See here on [Building SQL queries](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/building-a-query-expression.htm).  Assuming that's what you are trying to do, are you wanting to filter records that the update cursor returns based on that `character` value?

Comment: You should get used to reading python exceptions. All the exception messages you posted were very clear about what and where the problem was. Sadly this isn't always true, particularly when working with 3rd party libraries such as arcpy, i.e. the infamous [RuntimeError 99999](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/tool-errors-and-warnings/999001-999999/tool-errors-and-warnings-999998-999999-999999.htm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code you are defining a variable **in_features** which is the the path to the feature class. I think this is what you want to use to open the cursor.

```
def execute(self, parameters, messages):
    in_features = parameters[0].valueAsText
    ...
    ...
    if Character == "#":
       cur = arcpy.UpdateCursor(table)
```

try

```
cur = arcpy.UpdateCursor(in_features)
```

For your [query](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/building-a-query-expression.htm), depending on your storage format and field data type, your format should be something like:

```
....
if Character == "#":
       cur = arcpy.UpdateCursor(in_features)
else:
       query = """{} LIKE '%{}%'""".format(field,Character)
       cur = arcpy.UpdateCursor(in_features, query)
```

Comment: I am a bit confused now. I did change update cursor. but where should I put query part?

Comment: ...
    else:
           query = ...
           cur = arcpy.UpdateCursor(table, query)

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out. And YES, YES, YES. That's it. I didn't know that converting from regular toolbox to python toolbox could give such a headache.